# Function to check whether a sheet exists, in If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function to check whether a sheet exists. I cannot get it to work in an if statement.

I would rather not create a variable before the if statement which saves the results. Should I change the function to a sub?

```
sub tester()
    If ShExist("Equity") = True then call differentfunction
end sub

Function ShExist(name As String)
    Dim WorksheetExists
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & (name) & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Comment: Your ShExist function doesn't actually return anything as the 'answer' is stored in `WorksheetExists` not `ShExist`. See my answer below for better working function.

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function isn't complete or correct. The following would work:

```
Function ShExist(name As String)
    ShExist = Evaluate("ISREF('" & (name) & "'!A1)")
End Function
```